# Multiply every record in Double column with a decimal number

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a column 'Price' of type Double.
I also have a form with a button that should open an Inputbox to let the user enter the amount of discount they want, e.g. The user enters 0,6 (60% discount) and a calculation is done, 1 - 0,6 = 0,4. 0,4 is the number to multiply every record in the Price column with.
I don't seem to get this to work.

One of my tries when entering 0,5 only multiplied by 5, it skipped the 0, before the 5. which was weird.

```
Dim strDiscount As String
Dim discount  As Double
Dim holder As Double
Dim strSQL  As String
Dim dbs     As DAO.Database

Set dbs = CurrentDb

strDiscount = InputBox("Enter how much discount you want:", "Amount of discount")

holder = Val(strDiscount)
discount = (1-holder)
strSQL = "UPDATE Prislista SET Listpris = Listpris *" & _
discount
dbs.Execute strSQL
```

One of the tries gave an error messages telling me I have the wrong location set on my windows OS. Something about using comma instead of dot. Well, I have my windows and ms-access on swedish and it doesn't matter to me whether I should use comma or dot when entering the discount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, always store amounts and quantities as **Currency** if four decimals is adequate.

Next, use **CCur** to convert your localised text from **InputBox** to a number.

Third, use **Str** to convert a decimal to its neutral string expression.

Then:

```vb
Dim strDiscount As String
Dim discount  As Currency
Dim holder As Currency
Dim strSQL  As String
Dim dbs     As DAO.Database

Set dbs = CurrentDb

strDiscount = InputBox("Enter how much discount you want:", "Amount of discount")

holder = CCur(strDiscount)
discount = (1 - holder)
strSQL = "UPDATE Prislista SET Listpris = Listpris * " & Str(discount) & ""
dbs.Execute strSQL
```

Example:

```vb
strDiscount = "0,6"
holder = CCur(strDiscount)
discount = 1 - holder
? Str(discount)
 .4
```

Comment: Thanks you for answering! Something is not quite right though. Everything is set to zero in the price column

Comment: Then double-check your values/variables. Example added to answer.

Comment: Sorry! it was my fault, had an extra comma in the code. Thanks for the help, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

While the user interface in access will use your local settings, VBA uses US settings only.

So you'll need to convert `0,5` to `0.5`.

The below should work:

```
holder = Val(Replace(strDiscount,",","."))
```